# Why use state management in VueJs SPA?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to learn vue/vue-cli to make a Single-Page-Application.

I'm using the default `vue init webpack`

I want to use some data in multiple components. I also want to use some 'computed' variables in multiple places without having to 'recalculate' them.

For shared data everyone seems to recommend a state management system such as Vuex (or simpler alternatives of a plain object, yet from what I understand a plain object can't share a computed, and each component would have to recalculate that computed itself).

Since it's an SPA, there's a single focal point which I believe is App.vue, why can't I just have all my 'data' variables, and my 'computed' variables in App.vue, and in any other component just access the data I need via $root.SharedData or $root.MyComputed or something similar?

Am I misunderstanding something? Is there a major downside just using $root? I can't find much info about it.

Answer (score 0):

To get started you may find it easy to have everything at one place like App.vue, But in later stages it will be headache to seek synchronisation between different components/modules, it is always recommended to have all common stuff to reside in the 'state' and avoid direct DOM manipulation using actions and mutations. Go through the state diagram of [VUEX](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vuejs/vuex/dev/docs/en/images/vuex.png) and its life-cycle to understand the importance of state management, however Vue js is light-weighted.